# Algorithm to increase n^2 time

Tags: java, algorithm

Alright so I've got code that essentially loops through 30,000 lines of text, and for each line, it runs through 20,000,000 lines of text in another file to compare it with.

```
while(x.hasNextLine())
    while(y.hasNextLine())
```

where x has 30,000 and y has 20,000,000 lines respectively. Obviously, this is taking forever. Now I know of better algorithms, but I'm trying to compare a String in one with a String in another, so it's a little more difficult. I split a string in x, and I split a string in y. If part 1 of x, and part 2 of y are equal, I increment and do some other stuff. Generally, x appears in y a couple hundred times or so.

So, any ideas? I tried removing the line in y after each pass, and then rewriting the file so each time it parses through less in the second loop, but obviously this didn't help when you're writing a >500MB file.

Comment: *I split a string in x, and I split a string in y. If part 1 of x, and part 2 of y are equal*; Post that code please!

Comment: I don't think there will be room for significant improvement unless the text is sorted or in some particular order.

Comment: It would help if you provide your problem to solve in detail.

Comment: If you can, store the `String`s from `y.hasNextLine()` into a `Set<String>` and do the lookup of `x.hasNextLine()` against this `Set`. That will improve the code a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading right, you're reading from disk the 20M line (500MB) file 30,000 times?

If the 30k strings are small enough to keep in memory, you could reverse the inner/outer bits of the loop, and only go through the 500MB file once. Assuming DiskIO is the bottleneck, this'll save a lot of time.

Comment: And if a string can be deleted from `y` once found it will go even quicker.

Comment: Put the 30k in a hash in memory first.  Then it's one loop through 20M with constant lookup time for each.

Answer (score 0):

The kind of data that you're working with will really determine how you can speed it up.

For example:
If your strings have some structure to them, then you might consider arranging the 20000 set of strings into a kind of tree Data structure, where you only compare sections of one string to another, effectively reducing the total number of comparisons made to some subset of the 20k strings.

You could also take advantage of your CPU architecture by running on multiple threads at once.
Ie create a separate thread each time you run a compare vs the 20k strings.

Maybe if you post some examples of the strings you're using, it'll be easier to find optimisations, but otherwise be creative :)

**Edit:**
Also check out Multimap from the [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) package, provided by google. I remember using it for a small project of mine Yonks ago, that seems quite similar to what you're attempting. Maybe it'll help you out, since it provides a key/value data structure.